# Flash Builder converting number to string

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flash-builder, flexbuilder

I'm trying to calculate a BMI and set a label to the number, but it keeps returning "NaN" rather than the number.

Full code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="BMI Calculator">

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        public var weightnum:Number;
        public var heightnum:Number;
        public var resultvar:Number;
        protected function button1_clickHandler():void
        {
            weightnum = Number(weightvar);
            heightnum = Number(heightvar);
            resultvar = weightnum * 4.4 / (heightnum * heightnum);
            resultstr.text = resultvar.toString();
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<s:Label left="30" top="30" text="Your Weight (lbs)"/>
<s:TextInput id="weightvar" restrict="0-9" x="30" y="53" width="80%"/>
<s:Label x="30" y="104" text="Your Height (feet)"/>
<s:TextInput id="heightvar" restrict="0-9" x="30" y="127" width="80%"/>
<s:Button x="30" y="202" label="Calculate" click="button1_clickHandler()"/>
<s:Label id="resultstr" x="30" y="253" text="" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to cast the `TextInput`'s to a Number (`Number(weightvar);`).
That obviously won't work.

What you need to do is to cast the `TextInput`'s `text` property to a Number, just like this:

```
weightnum = Number(weightvar.text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of casting using String() use the number.toString()

Comment: No cigar, still get NaN if I do resultstr.text = resultvar.toString();